# An Executor with interrupts and more

Tags: java, multithreading, interrupt, executor

I have a task to be done every certain intervals of time, say every 3 millisecs till forever. 
So, at every point of time of x, x+3, x+2*3, ..., that task which is the method `m1()` will be invoked. 
This will all be happening in a class, say `SomeClass`

I can use a `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` and its `scheduleAtFixedRate()` to do this.

However, there can be more to be done during this scheduled task. The thread may receive new and unscheduled info, thru an interrupt. 
And when it does, it has to do certain things that a.) may effect the way `m1()` processes at those scheduled times by `scheduleAtFixedRate()`. 
or b.) may invoke `m1()` itself.

During this scheduled run, I'll have to update certan field members, say `field1` and `field2` of `SomeClass`.

```
class SomeClass {
int field1, field2;     

void m1() {...}

void theOne() {
    ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor trd = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
     trd.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            field1++; // line-F
            m1();
            // line-K 
            // whatever else here
         }
     }, 0, freq, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);


} // theOne()

} // SomeClass
```

1.) is the change of value of `field1` i'm making in "line-F" seen, i.e. am i incrementing the value of `field1` of this instance of `SomeClass` the way i intended to?

2.) how can i see the interrupts to this instance of SomeClass here?
let `anObj` be an instance of `SomeClass`. There will be calls to `anObj.interrupt()` elsewhere in the appication. When that happens, 
i have to see it and do further things in "line-K". How can i do that?

Way too new to `Executor`.

TIA.

//=============================

EDIT:

I can do the following:

change class declaration to

```
class SomeClass extends Thread {
```

this allows me to see the interrupts to `anObj` with the following in line K:

```
if (SomeClass.this.interrupted());
```

I'm aware that this isn't a good practice although i dont know why. Would this do or is there a better solution?

//=================================================

EDIT-2:

Interrupt here is not for exchanging info. just letting the thread know of something that happened. the interrupted thread will go from there the way its condition calls.

Comment: 1) seen by whom? in your version, it's guaranteed to be visible only for code after `line-F` in the same thread. 2) the most common and accepted approach for threads to exchange data is by using some subclass of `BlockingQueue`, not by interrupting.

Comment: Note that [`Interrupting a thread that is not alive need not have any effect.`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt--) So your `anObj.interrupt()` may not do anything if `anObj` is a `Thread` that wasn't started. What's more, the **thread** (not the object) that will be interrupted is different from the thread running within the `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor`. If you're only using it for notification, you might get away with it. A flag is probably better suited.

Answer (score 0):

You interrupt threads, not objects.

To do what you want the best option is to cancel the Future object

```
Future<?> future = trd.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
```

You can later do the following to cancel the task, interrupting it if already running

```
future.cancel(true);
```

To test if a thread has been interrupted you can do

```
if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())
```